# What is the process for getting maven url from my library plugin android project

Tags: android

Ca please Explain complete Steps to get maven URL don't know any basics of getting this.Please help!!!. i have tried https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html . But did not understand how to get url.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal ....Hello, i have added any code in android studio but i have created a maven project using the cmd followed by above link...if you specify me what code i need to add from begining it would be great help for me ...thanks in adavance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to upload your library to maven central.

so people can add it to Gradle with a url.

One of the best options is using [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/docs/)
They provide one of the easiest ways to upload a library to their repository which is almost the same as maven central

When a user uses it, it will looks like so

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
       maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
   }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.User:Repo:Version'
}
```

Another option is to actually upload it to maven central/ Jcenter
Look at this [tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) on how to upload it

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much. yes exactly what i want is this.I have followed the tutorial to upload in that jcenter and maven central i need pom.xml how to generate that file from android studio.Thank you

Comment: If it helped you then upvote it and set as approved answer